# How to properly cast my derived class?

Tags: c++, casting

I have a base class (`car`) and a class that inherit the base class (`honda`):

```
class car
{
    virtual void polymorphic_class()
    {   }
};

class honda : public car
{   };
```

When I use the following code and I cast my class a get a null pointer:

```
list<car> cars;
honda h;
cars.push_back(h);
honda* h_ptr = dynamic_cast<honda*>(&cars.back());
// h_ptr is NULL
```

Why? How I have to cast properly my object?

Comment: There is no way to correctly do that cast. Your list is a list of `car`s. It does not (and cannot) contain `honda`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polymorphism works on pointers and references, not on object instances.

In this case, your list contains objects of type `car`, not of any derived type. When you insert a `honda`, it will copy the `car` part and ignore the rest; this is sometimes referred to as *slicing*.

For polymorphism, you could use a list of pointers:

```
list<car*> cars {new honda};
honda * h_ptr = dynamic_cast<honda*>(cars.back()); // should be a valid pointer
```

NOTE: If you do allocate using `new` as in my example, remember to either `delete` them, or store smart pointers (like `std::unique_ptr<car>`) rather than raw pointers. You'll also need a virtual destructor in order to delete objects using a base-class pointer.

You can avoid the slicing problem by making the base class *abstract*; if it contains pure virtual functions, then you can't instantiate objects of that type, only of derived types that override those functions:

```
class car
{
    virtual ~car() {}
    virtual void do_something() = 0;
};

class honda : public car
{
    void do_something() {}
};
```

If you don't actually want an abstract interface (e.g. if you only access derived-class functionality using `dynamic_cast` rather than through virtual functions), then you could make the destructor pure virtual instead; then the derived classes won't have to explicitly override anything. The base class destructor must still be implemented and, due to a quirk of the language, that implementation must be outside the class definition:

```
class car
{
    virtual ~car() = 0;
};
inline car::~car() {}

class honda : public car {};
```

This is a somewhat unusual approach, since polymorphism through virtual functions is usually more efficient and more convenient.

Answer (score 4):

The reason this doesn't work is **object slicing**. The objects in `cars` are no longer `honda`s, but just cars.

You need a vector of pointers or smart pointers:

```
list<car*> cars;
honda h;
cars.push_back(&h);
honda* h_ptr = dynamic_cast<honda*>(cars.back());
```

I'd actually change the design and make `car` abstract (pure virtual destructor or something). That way you'll also get a compilation error.

Comment: @Nick But wouldn't you like one?

Comment: @Nick I know you're not getting one now, but if you had one you could spot these problems early on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
list<car*> cars;
honda *h = new honda();
cars.push_back(h);
honda* h_ptr = dynamic_cast<honda*>(cars.back());
```

This works.